# How can I change XMobar's Kbd monitor plugin such that clicking on it loops throught the layouts?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, xmonad, io-monad, xmobar

The [`Kbd`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org#user-content-headline-24) monitor plugin can be installed in the xmobar status bar like this,

```hs
Run $ Kbd [("it", "IT"), ("ru(phonetic)", "RU")]
```

and then switch keyboard via `setxkbmap`, the monitor will reflect the change.

So far so good.

Now, assume that

- I want to make the monitor clickable,
- and that the click should "rotate" the keyboard layout (among those provided, see the `[]` above)

even if this means writing `MyOwnKbd` plugin.

Also assume that another requirement is that I don't want the logic of rotation to be encoded in an external script.

---

Since I don't want to bind a key to switching between keyboards¹, I was thinking about allowing the switch via clicking on the monitor itself.

I know I can just wrap the text of the monitor in `` <action=`the command`> `` and `</action>` to make it clickable, but I have no clue what `the command` should be.

I know that I could write a shell script that detects the state of the keyboard and sets the other one, but I want to use the very list above, `[("it", "IT"), ("ru(phonetic)", "RU")]` as the source of what keyboard layouts clicking the monitor should loop through, so the question becomes: can I feed the click-on-monitor event back to the business logic of the monitor?

Or, if that's not possible, what other alternatives do I have?

---

(¹) E.g. I could have done

```bash
setxkbmap -layout it,ru -variant ,phonetic -option 'grp:caps_toggle'
```

once and for all, and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> would allow to switch between those two layouts, and the plugin, as is, would reflect which layout is in use. But I don't want to map any key to the layout switching action.

Well, it's not that I don't want that solution, but I'm curious to know what another solution would be.

---

(I've deleted [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78149534/how-can-i-feed-the-event-that-an-xmobar-plugin-monitor-has-been-clicked-back-to) because the specific scenario that led me to formulate it was actually complicating the matter. I'll un-delete it if the answer to this question will be insufficient for that.)

Comment: Note that `Kbd` only offers a string replacement for display, no actual switching, and there's no standard CLI cmd to rotate the layout. But there are plenty of tools that fill in the gap, e.g. [xkb-switch](https://github.com/grwlf/xkb-switch) (written in C++) or [rotate-keyboard-layout](https://github.com/thusoy/rotate-keyboard-layout) (written in Python). With some effort, this is also doable in a shell script by manually keeping track, and using `setxkbmap` accordingly. Whichever you chose, just use that program or script as the command in `<action=command>` to invoke it with a mouse click.

Comment: @pmf, I see your point and that might be the solution I'll eventually go for, but I'm excluding it for now because (1) yes, I know how to do that, and (2) I want to understand what are the most viable and/or appropriate solutions for writing an xmobar plugin that can react to clicks _with its code_, rather than indirectly via an external command. I'll try to rephrase the question to stress this point.

Comment: @pmf, I have managed to do enhance the plugin to swtich keyboards :)

Answer (score 0):

[Eventually I came up with a solution myself](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/pulls/696/files), which was merged with the [PR #696](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/pulls/696/commits).

When I wrote

> I know I can just wrap the text of the monitor in `` <action=`the command`> `` and `</action>` to make it clickable, but I have no clue what the command should be.

I was making the mistake of thinking that I have to know `the command` that does the right thing whatever the current layout, but that's incorrect, as I can just compute a different command for each layout, which will simply switch to the next one.

To give a concrete example, if I install the plugin like this,

```hs
Run $ Kbd [("it", "IT"), ("ru(phonetic)", "RU"), ("us", "US")]
```

the text I want to print when each of the 3 layouts is selected is as follows:

- `` "<action=`setxkbmap -layout ru -variant phonetic` button=1>IT</action>" ``
- `` "<action=`setxkbmap -layout us` button=1>RU</action>" ``
- `` "<action=`setxkbmap -layout it` button=1>US</action>" ``

This allow switching layouts in the order `IT`->`RU`->`US`. In the code I've contributed to xmobar, I've also wrapped those in actions to navigate the opposite direction with `button=3`.